# Run a batch file using createProcess()

Tags: windows, batch-file, createprocess

Is it necessary to set lpApplicationName to cmd.exe as mentioned in the documentation to run a batch file?

- "port=5598 dbname=demo host=localhost"
- "port=5599 dbname=demo host=localhost"
- "C:/tmp/000002AB-1.16432"
- "C:/bin/pg_restore.exe"

Assume that the path of the batch file is "C:/Users/abc.bat".
How can i pass the above strings are to be passed as arguments to the batch file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assumming a standard configuration, the answer is no, it is not *required*. You can include the batch file in the `lpCommandLine` argument. The remaining arguments just follow the batch file with quotes where needed.

**test.cmd**

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion
    echo %1  
    echo %~1
    echo %2  
    echo %~2
```

**test.c**

```c
#define _WIN32_WINNT   0x0500
#include <windows.h>

void main(void){

    // Spawn process variables
    STARTUPINFO si;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;

    ZeroMemory( &si, sizeof(si) );
    si.cb = sizeof(si);
    ZeroMemory( &pi, sizeof(pi) );

    CreateProcess(
        NULL
        , "\"test.cmd\" \"x=1 y=2\" \"x=3 y=4\""
        , NULL
        , NULL
        , TRUE
        , 0
        , NULL
        , NULL
        , &si
        , &pi 
    );

    WaitForSingleObject( pi.hProcess, INFINITE );
    CloseHandle( pi.hProcess );
    CloseHandle( pi.hThread );    
};
```

**Output**

```
W:\>test.exe
"x=1 y=2"
x=1 y=2
"x=3 y=4"
x=3 y=4
```